# Alternatives to splitting tables Entity Framework 6 - VARBINARY(MAX)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**Solution :**
The idea is that the loading problem was from the table files. So in order to get everything in order, I had to turn off lazy load, and load the navigation property from the entity with the blob instead of the other way around.

```
  public FileDto[] RetrieveFilesWithUserId(string id)
        {
            FileDto[] files;
            logger.Info("Looking for files #{0}", id);
            using (var db = ContextFactory.GetEntities())
            {
                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                logger.Debug("User retrieved !");

                files = db.Files.Include("Users").Where(f => f.Users.Count(user1 => user1.Id == id) > 0).Select(
                    x =>
                        new FileDto
                        {
                            ContentType = x.ContentType,
                            Id = x.Id,
                            Name = x.Name,
                            Type = db.TypeFiles.FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == x.Type).Description
                        }).ToArray();

                db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
            }

            logger.Info("done looking for files");
            return files;
        }
```

**Problem was:**
I have an issue which seems quite classic. 
I have a table with one large blob, and when I load it I have huge performance issues (due to loading large amount of data).

I have users, those users have files and in my file entity I have the datas.
Relations are many to many.

Easy fix: I do some table splitting, and all my problems are solved.

Problem: My boss doesn't want me to do that (I argued that this was the best option).

So, how can I do differently ? 
I thought about requiring directly but I don't have access to the intermediate tables (they are navigation properties now.)
Would a procedure make the trick ?

Comment: What kind of files are the big files?

Comment: What do you mean ? All kind of files, pictures pdf etc ... its just a varbinary(max) field that I want (sometime ) to avoid to load (but that I need other times)

Comment: Why not keeping a pointer to the location of the files, instead of loading them in the database ?

Comment: Not really an option, I need my files saved in my db

Comment: SQL Filestream should be used for storing files, blobs are bad exactly for this reason

Answer (score 0):

You can use projection to get all fields you want without blob:

```
var people = context.People.Select(p => new PersonDTO { Id = p.Id, Name = p.Name });
```

Where PersonDTO is like:

```
class ProductDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DTO means [Data Transfer Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) and it is often used for such tasks.